# Is there a GPO for prompting login for accessing network resources?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, network-share, permissions

I get the error message that I don't have the right privileges to access the network resource (and that is correct) when I want to access my network share from a workstation (Windows 7) in the domain. But it's only a error message.. No prompt for entering a account with the good privileges as by Windows XP.

I hate it to mount the network share everytime with the command prompt (net use \servername\share * /user:domain\user). Is there not a GPO that will force a user login prompt when accessing a network share without the right privileges?

Comment: Why do you have to connect as a different user to access the resource? It would be so much easier to just grant access to your own account.

Comment: Because it's for connecting to the resource when I'm at a workstation of a user. And I never want to grand everyone access to that resource, only staff of IT.

Answer (score 0):

I have not attempted this, but after a quick search for "Force interactive logon network shares" I found this [suggestion](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=7035), which seems to have addressed the problem you're having.
Give it a go.

```
hklm\software\microsoft\windowsnt\current version\winlogon

set **cachedlogons** to 0
```